# How to generate HTML5 valid Javadoc?

Tags: java, eclipse, html, java-8, javadoc

I have generated HTML5 JavaDoc in the Eclipse Luna clicking `Project` -> `Generate Javadoc...`

The output is well-formated standard Javadoc HTML file, however, it's not HTML5 valid. For example, I find it not appropriate since I would like to upload the whole documentation to a website.

I have tested the generated files with [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

How to force the generator to produce the HTML5 valid file including `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of the page and avoiding obsolete elements such as `frameset` or the incomplete elements at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On current (Photon) Eclipse select your project in Package Explorer view and go to :

Project > Generate Javadoc ...

This brings you to page 1 of the Javadoc set-up.
After selecting the Javadoc command path, the project, the visibility and the output folder, click the *Next* button **twice** to get to page 3 of the set-up where you may enter various options for the Javadoc.exe command.
Enter *-html5* as your VM option.

It is best to enter *-noqualifier all* in the Javadoc options box in order to remove qualifier prefixes from each class. Otherwise the objects in the final Javadoc's **Modifier & Type** and **Method** columns would be given as java.lang.String rather than String and ArrayList as java.util.ArrayList. (It gets longer and sillier still for HashMap classes with proprietary classes) The effect of this is to slow down readability of the docs and reduce the available width of the (most important) **Description** column.

You can also add other options for things like custom tags here, e.g.

```
 -tag custom.date:a:"Date: "
```

so that the tag

```
  @custom.date: November 2018
```

shows as

```
  Date: November 2018
```

in the final Javadoc.

Finally click *Finish* button to start generating javadocs in HTML5 format.

[image: Javadoc display configuration]

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell this will be available in jdk-9 via [jep-224](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/224). In java 8 current type is `html4`.

Comment: Indeed, the JDK 9 `javadoc` has a `-html5` option, but the JDK8 one doesn't. Eclipse uses the JDK javadoc tool too, so when it's available you can use that command line option.

Comment: @Jorn It's available now at [jdk.java.net/9/](http://jdk.java.net/9/) but the last few builds have had fixes for HTML5 so it may not be perfect yet, and it probably won't work with Luna, but may work with Neon or Oxygen.